# How to generate gpg signing keys in bintray for jcenter in windows

Tags: repository, gnupg, bintray, jcenter

I am unable to get GPG signing keys. Please any one tell me. Thanks
[image]
How to generate gps signing keys in windows for jcenter

Comment: This tutorial was useful: https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-upload-library-to-jcenter-maven-central-as-dependency/en

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows users can generate GPG keys using [GPG4Win](https://www.gpg4win.org/).
There are many tutorials available, for example [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2XUAazWkN04).

Comment: Please replace the second link. That website has been seized by the FBI.

Answer (score 10):

For Linux/Mac you can use `gpg`. I learned how to do this [here](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-upload-library-to-jcenter-maven-central-as-dependency/en). I needed to prefix the following commands with `sudo`.

1. Generate the keys

   ```
   gpg --gen-key
   ```

   Follow the defaults but enter your name and email and optionally a password.
2. List the keys.

   ```
   gpg --list-keys
   ```

   which should show something like this:

   ```
   pub   2038R/91E83BF2 2017-05-13
   uid                  Bob <name@example.com>
   sub   2038R/E3872671 2017-05-13
   ```
3. Upload the public key to a keyserver

   ```
   gpg --keyserver hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net --send-keys PUBLIC_KEY_ID
   ```

   replacing `PUBLIC_KEY_ID` with your id (`91E83BF2` in the example above).
4. Export your public and private keys to a text file

   ```
   gpg -a --export name@example.com > public_key_sender.asc
   gpg -a --export-secret-key name@example.com > private_key_sender.asc
   ```
5. Copy the contents of these files to Bintray at Edit Profile > GPG signing.

[image]

Comment: Also in console GPGsigning option is not there

Comment: @DeepPatel, did you use `sudo`?

Comment: I got "no route to host" for `hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net` but was able to push to `hkp://ipv4.pool.sks-keyservers.net`

Comment: gpg -a --export name@example.com > public_key_sender.asc What does this command do? I didnt recieve anything on my mail.

Comment: @niranjankurambhatti i am also facing same issue that there in no any issue when i run the step 4 command but i haven't receive anything in mail. have you got the solution?

Comment: @Ninja This doesn't send an email. It just creates a file called ‛public_key_sender.asc‛.

Comment: @Ninja You dont recieve any mail. I got my key on the command prompt itself.

Comment: @niranjankurambhatti ok, i got the solution from [here](https://www.deepdotweb.com/2015/02/21/pgp-tutorial-for-windows-kleopatra-gpg4win/) but i just want to know that from where we can find that key in our system ?

Comment: `gpg: keyserver send failed: Network is unreachable`

Comment: @Suragch I've followed the same steps to generate the key but, the public ID is not 8 characters. It's something like `09AF53E4FCF6163E85FE9391F09001AB408F78CA`

Comment: @Dr.jacky, I don't recall why I wrote a short string for public id key in the examples above, but yes, replace it with the long one that you actually get.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice tutorial for gen `gpg-key` https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-gpg-key/

**Some note**

-For Ubuntu 14.04 we need to use `gpg --gen-key` instead of `gpg --full-generate-key` https://askubuntu.com/questions/1019793/how-to-solve-gpg-invalid-option-full-generate-key.

-For gen private key

```
gpg --armor --export-secret-keys {sec_value}
eg: gpg --armor --export-secret-keys 3AA5C34371567BD2
```

-When copy public key or private key, remember copy **ALL** (including `-----BEGIN ...-----` and `-----END ...-----`)

Answer (score 0):

I found solution, I needed it configure gpg signing in bintray. If you not created gpg keys follow this tutorial: https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-gpg-key/

After you created gpg keys if you do not know how to copy private key in armored form follow this steps on git bash:

1. list private keys: `gpg --list-secret-keys`
2. copy long string after(or below) [SC]
3. export armored private key: `gpg --export-secret-keys --armor string you have copied > private_key.asc`
4. open private_key.asc with some editor(i used sublime text), and copy your private key

Hope it helps