# Android Studio gradle bintray upload failed: Could not sign version

Tags: android-studio, bintray, jcenter, gpg-signature

After running

```
./gradlew bintrayUpload
```

I am getting the following error.

> :my-library:bintrayUpload FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':my-library:bintrayUpload'.
>
>   > Could not sign version '0.8.1': HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request [message:Private key is required, please supply it by using a JSON
>   >     body or alternatively you can stored in your Bintray profile]
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
> BUILD FAILED

It had been working previously when I installed GPG authentication as described in [this tutorial](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-upload-library-to-jcenter-maven-central-as-dependency/en).

However, when I tried to update the version (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44623870/3681880)) it stopped working.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by deleting the GPG key in Bintray and then [regenerating the keys](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45750186/3681880).

[image]

Comment: I just spent 2 hous debugging until I did this and the upload worked. Thanks!

Comment: Facing same issue. But now getting error as
message:The private key requires a passphrase, please supply a passphrase.

Comment: "2 Hours later": Disabled gpg signing

Answer (score 2):

This happens mostly after the `local.properties` file is regenerated.

Instead of generating a new key, if you still remember the password, in your `local.propreties` file just add this line:

```
bintray.gpg.password= yourpassowrd
```